# カルーセルUIコンポーネントで画像の幅に合わせて自動的に高さを調整したい

Tags: onsen-ui

Onsen UIのカルーセル（ons-carousel）で
画像の幅に合わせて高さを自動で出すことはできないのでしょうか？
高さを指定しないと表示がされないのですが
表示に合わせて伸び縮みしてほしいのですが何か書き方があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

```css
ons-carousel{
  position:static;
}
ons-carousel-item{
  overflow:hidden;
  height:initial !important;
}
```

`ons-carousel-item`の下に`<img>`を配置しただけという想定で。こんな感じでCSSをいじるといいんじゃないでしょうか。